# Change font after subtitle in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I have an environment created with `tcolorbox` where the upper part is in bold text, and the lower part is not. Sometimes I use `\tcbsubtitle` inside this environment, and I would like that to correspond to the separation of the upper and lower part. If I do not use `\tcbsubtitle`, then `\tcblower` adds the correct amount of space, but if I use `\tcbsubtitle` in addition, the space becomes too much.

I realize that the purpose of `\tcbsubtitle` is not to start the lower part of the box, but since the only difference between the upper and the lower part is the font weight, I thought I could get `\tcbsubtitle` to change the font following it. I did try the following without success:

```
\tcbset{
    subtitle style = {after  = {\normalfont}}
}
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{example}{Example}{
    middle           = 1em,
    lower separated  = false,
    fontupper        = \bfseries\boldmath\raggedright,
    fontlower        = \raggedright,
    fonttitle        = \bfseries\boldmath\raggedright,
}{ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcblower % Appropriate amount of vertical space
    Normal text
\end{example}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcblower % Too much space
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    Normal text
\end{example}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle} % Appropriate amount of vertical space
    Bold text              % Still bold
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below has a conditional `\ifLower`, toggled `true` immediately after entering the lower part. The `\tcbsubtitle` is redefined to use this conditional to detect if it is the first subtitle in the lower part, and if it is, `\vspace{-2em}` is applied. The result looks like below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newif\ifLower\Lowerfalse

\newtcbtheorem{example}{Example}{
    before lower     = {\Lowertrue},
    middle           = 1em,
    lower separated  = false,
    subtitle style   = {height = 1.5em},
    fontupper        = \bfseries\boldmath,
    fonttitle        = \bfseries\boldmath,
    fontlower        = \normalfont,
}{ex}

\let\tcbsubtitleOriginal=\tcbsubtitle
\renewcommand{\tcbsubtitle}{%
    \ifLower\vspace{-2em}\fi%
    \Lowerfalse%
    \tcbsubtitleOriginal%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcblower
    Normal text
\end{example}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcblower
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    Normal text
\end{example}

\begin{example}{}{}
    Bold text
    \tcblower
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    Normal text
    \tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}
    Normal text 2
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This suggestion does not work if the same box contains multiple `\tcbsubtitle`.

Comment: @user44413 Check my new edit, this should work.